# What is the purpose of 'bouncing' in iOS?

Tags: ios, user-interface, hig

In beta testing an iOS application I wrote, I received some feedback to let more elements 'bounce', even if there isn't more content to see, or load in.

While I don't think its necessarily a bad suggestion it got me thinking - what is the purpose of allowing this behavior on UI elements? Is this stated in the HIG somewhere that I missed?

Comment: Close vote for migrating to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: How is this better suited to Programmers - it has to do with a specific technology stack?

Comment: There are [iphone](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ios](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios) tags available there as well. It seems better suited since the question does not address any technical issues.

Comment: Fair enough, although there are plenty* of questions on here that do not address any technical issues (e.g. this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456188/what-is-it-called-to-make-my-ui-pretty) and I thought it might benefit this community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the list bounces you know that it is at the end instead of just frozen or something. It feels good to get feedback whenever you touch something even if nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1):

While this question is better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com, I shall answer it the best I can here:

- It gives the user feedback that something is happening
- It helps to prevent the user from accidentally doing something they may not want to do (cancel editing, delete important data) etc.